# Modernists versus postmodernists?

Tags: postmodernism, modernism

Do modernists and postmodernist tend to hold the same views, or are these two disciplines simply unrelated?

Comment: [Postmodernism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/postmodernism/) has been identified by Lyotard and includes philophers like Deleuze, Derrida, Vattimo. They "react" to previous philosophers (they call them *modernist*) and take nspiration from Nietzsche, etc. But there is **no** previous "movement" that call itself *modernism*.

Comment: Good answer. But the confusion arises from the fact that I know someone who has studied modernism as part of a PhD in English literature but was unable to grasp what the subject was about, and having searched Wikipedia and still failed to understand I thought this site would be the best place to ask for clarification. Perhaps someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting that postmodernism is based on the notion that arts are separate from the sciences, which they are not. Science and logical thought can take over everything and it is impossible to reason decently without such tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean for something to be "post-modernist" as opposed to "modernist"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2665/what-does-it-mean-for-something-to-be-post-modernist-as-opposed-to-modernist)

Comment: See table comparisons (not necessarily within philosophy, but general flavour) e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ihab_Hassan), [here in Russian](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postmodernism is a response to modernism with less optimism about human progress. Both modernism and postmodernism hold that the previous philosophies are obsolete, and they rebel against classical culture through abstract and postmodern art. The difference is that modernism is optimistic about humans' ability to achieve progress while postmodernists hold all value as relative and do not necessarily believe in progress.